# SQL INNER JOIN DELETE ERROR: Not unique table/alias

Tags: sql, inner-join, sql-delete

I am trying to delete values from two tables using an inner join. The problem I am having is I get the error 'Not unique table/alias'

So here are my two tables with example rows inserted

MemberShipCore

| UserId | StartDate | EndDate | MemberShipId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022-01-01 | 2024-01-01 | 4 |

MemberShipType

| MemberShipId | Gym | Cardio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 0 |

I am trying to delete both rows in one sql statement

The statement I have so far is this:

```
DELETE `UserId`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `MembersipCore`.`MemberShipId`,  `MembershipType`.`MemberShipId`, `Gym`, `Cardio` FROM `MembershipType`, `MembershipCore` INNER JOIN `MembershipCore` ON `MemberShipType`.`MemberShipId` = `MembershipCore`.`MemberShipId`
```

When running this in phpmyadmin I am given the error message

```
Error
SQL query: Copy

DELETE `UserId`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `MembersipCore`.`MemberShipId`,  `MembershipType`.`MemberShipId`, `Gym`, `Cardio` FROM `MembershipType`, `MembershipCore` INNER JOIN `MembershipCore` ON `MemberShipType`.`MemberShipId` = `MembershipCore`.`MemberShipId`;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'MembershipCore'
```

Comment: You can’t delete records from multiple tables using a single SQL statement

Comment: Not sure what DB that you have as there is no tag, but with MySQL/MariaDB it is possible to delete from multiple tables, but the syntax you have is not right. At [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) scroll down to the section about `Multi-Table Deletes` to see examples.